# Variable importance from a tidymodels/stacks output?

Tags: stack, tidymodels, vip

Is it possible to retrieve the variable importance for one, many, or the full stacked model after running tidymodels/stacks? This is not yet supported by the VIP package, but is there an alternative method to extracting that information?

Using the bulk of the blog from Simon Couch [here](https://blog--simonpcouch.netlify.app/blog/gentle-intro-stacks/) this is what I am generally trying to attempt. Instead I will use random forests and SVMs to then try to retrieve a variable importance.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(stacks)
library(vip)

wind_raw <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-10-27/wind-turbine.csv')

wind <-
  wind_raw %>%
  dplyr::select(
    province_territory, 
    total_project_capacity_mw,
    turbine_rated_capacity_kw = turbine_rated_capacity_k_w,
    rotor_diameter_m,
    hub_height_m,
    year = commissioning_date
  ) %>%
  group_by(province_territory) %>%
  mutate(
    year = as.numeric(year),
    province_territory = case_when(
      n() < 50 ~ "Other",
      TRUE ~ province_territory
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(year)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  drop_na(turbine_rated_capacity_kw)

# split into training and testing sets
set.seed(1)
wind_split <- initial_split(wind)
wind_train <- training(wind_split)
wind_test  <- testing(wind_split)

# use a 5-fold cross-validation
set.seed(1)
folds <- rsample::vfold_cv(wind_train, v = 5)

# set up a basic recipe
wind_rec <- 
  recipe(turbine_rated_capacity_kw ~ ., data = wind_train) %>%
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors())

# define a minimal workflow
wind_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(wind_rec)

ctrl_res <- control_stack_resamples()

rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(), 
              min_n = tune(), 
              trees = 1000) %>%
  set_mode('regression') %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")

# add it to a workflow
rf_wflow <- 
  wind_wflow %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec)

# tune cost and rand_forest and fit to the 5-fold cv
set.seed(1)
rf_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    rf_wflow , 
    resamples = folds, 
    grid = 5,
    control = ctrl_grid
  )

# define a model using parsnip
svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf(
    cost = tune(), 
    rbf_sigma = tune()
  ) %>%
  set_engine("kernlab") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

# add it to a workflow
svm_wflow <- 
  wind_wflow %>% 
  add_model(svm_spec)

# tune cost and rbf_sigma and fit to the 5-fold cv
set.seed(1)
svm_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    svm_wflow, 
    resamples = folds, 
    grid = 5,
    control = ctrl_grid
  )

# add the models to the stack
wind_data_st <- 
  stacks() %>%
  add_candidates(rf_res) %>%
  add_candidates(svm_res) %>%
  blend_predictions() %>%
  fit_members()

# attempt to plot the variable importance of the stacked model
wind_data_st %>%
  vip()
```

I return `Error: Model-specific variable importance scores are currently not available for this type of model.`, which is self explanatory, but is there a work around to extract this information? Maybe outside of VIP?  Is it possible to pluck out one of the viable models that went into the stack to evaluated? Does anyone know if VIP is planning on putting out a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mostly use the vip package for model-specific variable importance and the DALEX package for model-agnostic variable importance. We have a [draft chapter on these topics here](https://github.com/tidymodels/TMwR/pull/151) so you can take a look at that and then look for more info on this soon.

Comment: @JuliaSilge Thank you for the help! I have not heard of the DELAX package - sounds exactly what I need.  Appreciate you passing along the draft chapter.  Excited to see what tidymodels will produce to accomplish this! Thanks again and for your great work on the tidymodels package :)

Comment: @nate-m Hi, just a quick follow up question are you able to use dalex package with stack ensemble model (from package stacks)? or any option for explainable model compatible to be used with stacks package?

Comment: @TengkuHanis Yes I did figure it out thanks to the direction for Julia Silge.  They have since published the chapter she was referring to - you can find it here. https://www.tmwr.org/explain.html or https://github.com/tidymodels/TMwR/blob/main/18-explaining-models-and-predictions.Rmd . I also found a book by the authors of the DALEX package to be very helpful.  https://ema.drwhy.ai/modelLevelExploration.html

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, and what I've done is make a tibble of variable importance for each member of the stack, then normalize them onto the same scale, and multiply by their relative weight in the stack to have a summed total relative importance.

I couldn't reproduce your code, but here's an example of what you can try...

After you've ran blend_predictions(), you can extract the weights. Then create a tibble for each that includes a column for Variable and a column for importance. Then join together and you'll have the weight importance.

```
library("DALEX")
library("dplyr")
library("tidymodels")


colnames(fifa)
fifa_small <- fifa %>% 
  select(value_eur, age, 
         attacking_crossing:attacking_volleys, 
         defending_marking:defending_sliding_tackle) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% dplyr::slice_sample(n = 1000)


fifa_small_folds <- vfold_cv(fifa_small, v = 8, repeats = 1)
fifa_small_folds


basic_rec <-   
  recipe(value_eur ~ ., data = fifa_small) %>%
  step_nzv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) 


model1 <- 
  boost_tree(trees = 1000) %>%
  set_engine('xgboost', importance = TRUE) %>%
  set_mode('regression')


model2 <-
  linear_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>%
  set_engine('glmnet')

model3 <-
  linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = 0) %>%
  set_engine('glmnet')

wfs <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(basic_rec),  
    models = list(model1, model2, model3), 
    cross = T  )

wfs

doParallel::registerDoParallel()

wfs_rs <-
  workflow_map(
    wfs,
    "tune_grid",
    resamples = fifa_small_folds,
    grid = 10,
    control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE,
                           parallel_over = "everything",
                           save_workflow = TRUE
                           
    ) )


doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()


library(stacks)
tidymodels_prefer()

wfs_stack <- 
  stacks() %>% 
  add_candidates(wfs_rs)


blend_ens <- blend_predictions(wfs_stack, penalty = 10^seq(-2, 0, length = 10))

blend_ens

ens1_wt <- stacks:::top_coefs(blend_ens) %>% slice(1) %>%  pull(weight)
ens2_wt <- stacks:::top_coefs(blend_ens) %>% slice(2) %>% pull(weight)

## Get the workflowset
individ_ens1_best_fit <- extract_workflow(wfs_rs, id = "recipe_boost_tree")

## extract the tuned results from the workflow
individ_ens1_best_tuned <- wfs_rs[wfs_rs$wflow_id == "recipe_boost_tree",
                                            "result"][[1]][[1]]

individ_ens1_lowest_rmse <- individ_ens1_best_tuned %>%
  show_best("rmse") %>% 
  slice(1)

## fit the final model
individ_ens1_best_final <- finalize_workflow(individ_ens1_best_fit, individ_ens1_lowest_rmse)
individ_ens1_bestfinal_1 <- individ_ens1_best_final %>% fit(fifa_small)


individ_ens1_vi_tbl <- individ_ens1_bestfinal_1 %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  vip::vi() %>%
  mutate(
    ens1_Importance = abs(Importance),
    Variable = factor(Variable), .keep = "unused") 



blend_ens

ens2_config <- ens_name_fn(blend_ens, 2)
ens2_id <- ens_id_fn(blend_ens, 2)

## Get the  workflowset
individ_ens2_best_fit <- extract_workflow(wfs_rs, id = "recipe_linear_reg_3")


## extract the tuned results from the best workflow
individ_ens2_best_tuned <- wfs_rs[wfs_rs$wflow_id == "recipe_linear_reg_3",
                                            "result"][[1]][[1]]


individ_ens2_lowest_rmse <- individ_ens2_best_tuned %>%
  show_best("rmse") %>% filter(.config == "Preprocessor1_Model01") %>%  slice(1)

## fit the final model
individ_ens2_best_final <- finalize_workflow(individ_ens2_best_fit, individ_ens2_lowest_rmse)

individ_ens2_bestfinal_1 <- individ_ens2_best_final %>% fit(fifa_small)


individ_ens2_vi_tbl <- individ_ens2_bestfinal_1 %>%
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>%
  vip::vi(lambda = individ_ens2_lowest_rmse$penalty) %>%   # include lambda for lasso or ridge
  mutate(
    ens2_Importance = abs(Importance),
    Variable = factor(Variable), .keep = "unused")


ens_vi_joined <- individ_ens1_vi_tbl %>% 
  left_join(individ_ens2_vi_tbl, by = c("Variable")) %>%
  mutate(across(2:ncol(.), ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)),
         ens1_normed = ens1_Importance/ sum(ens1_Importance),
         ens2_normed =  ens2_Importance/ sum(ens2_Importance),
         ens1_wted = ens1_normed * ens1_wt,
         ens2_wted = ens2_normed * ens2_wt,
  )  %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(summed_importance = sum(c_across(ends_with("wted")))  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(
    total_importance = summed_importance/ sum(summed_importance),   #normalized
  ) 


ens_vi_joined %>% select(Variable, total_importance) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(total_importance, fct_reorder(Variable, total_importance)))+
  geom_col()
```